# execMatch only returning first result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I am trying to find a particular record (with an id of `1`) and then to return only its `history` field. This `history` field is an array of objects with a `timestamp` property. When I return this history field, I want it to contain only objects with `timestamp` properties greater than `0`.

**Sample collection**

```
[{
    "_id" : 1,
    "history" : [
        {
            "content" : "hello",
            "timestamp" : 1394639953878,
            "_id" : ObjectId("53208451767743b748ddbd7d")
        },
        {
            "content" : "world",
            "timestamp" : 1394639953879,
            "_id" : ObjectId("33208451767743b748ddbd7e")
        }
    ]
}]
```

Thus, according to Mongo and Mongoose documentation, I do something like:

```
model.find({_id: 1})
     .select({ history: { $elemMatch: { timestamp: { $gt: 0 } } } });
```

**The issue:** I understand that there will only be one result (since I select the id `1`) but I am using `$elemMatch` to populate its `history` field with **all** objects that have a timestamp greater than `0`. The issue is that only one object is ever in `history`.

Comment: What's the "timestamp" for?

Comment: `timestamp` is just an arbitrary numerical property on the objects contained in the `history` field.

Comment: Can you please post a sample document?

Comment: Added a sample collection.

Comment: Your specifically select an document by_id field know??

Comment: _Id field is unique one..  So collection will ve only 1 doc with that Id

Comment: I understand that there will only be one result (since I select the id `1`) but I am using `$elemMatch` to populate its `history` field with **all** objects that have a timestamp greater than `0`. The issue is that only one object is ever in `history`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $elemMatch projection returns only the first matching element satisfying the condition.  Checkout the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

Using aggregate would be the right approach to achieve what you want I think.  Please see below:

```
db.bar.aggregate([
{$match:{_id:1}}, 
{$unwind:"$history"}, 
{$match:{"history.timestamp":{$gt:0}}}, 
{$group:{_id:"$_id", history:{$push:"$history"}}}
])
```

Comment: Oh, it looks like I was reading the [query documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for `elemMatch` rather than the projection documentation. Very confusing.

Comment: You are right, it is confusing.  If I find out a way to accomplish what you are trying to do, I'll post here.

Comment: Thank you! I will do the same.

Comment: I've posted an alternate approach.  Give it a shot.